# Retrieving data from plist is null

Tags: ios, plist, tableview

I can't display the items in a CustomCell. If I make name like `name` and `surname` everything works fine. But when I remove `surname field` and put them together in a field they are `null`. I guess it's because the `space character`. The same thing occurs for the depart field too. I don't know how I solve this. I'm new at IOS development.

AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)chackDB{

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *docPath = [[self documentsDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"drList.plist"];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:docPath]) return;

    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                            pathForResource:@"drList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSError *err=nil;
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:docPath error:&err];

    if(err){

        NSLog(@"hata: %@",[err description]);
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self chackDB];
```

Here is my plist:

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>depart</key>
            <string>Plastic Surgery</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>John Smith</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

My code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellid";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                              loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil]
                             lastObject];
    }

    // customization
    NSDictionary *d = [self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           [d objectForKey:@"name"]];

    cell.departLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           [d objectForKey:@"depart"]];


    cell.indexPath = indexPath;


    return cell;
}
```

Here is the DetailViewController when I select the row:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",[self.userInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
    self.depart.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Department: %@",[self.userInfo objectForKey:@"depart"]];

}
```

Comment: Please reset simulator or remove app from the device and clean build then reinstall app in your simulator or device it may be solve your problem?

Comment: Have you tried NSLog'ing your `d` dictionary to see what is inside it? Or the `self.dataList`? How are you making `self.dataList`?

Comment: Please show how you are forming dataList?

Comment: I restarted it and not nothing appears in the tableview :/. I defined datalist in the .h file. So I can. But that's not the point, I guess. Because when there is one word everythings fine. But when there is two words in name or depart field it returns null. I use the xcode's UI for plist to put the values in it.

Comment: There is no reason it should not work when there are two words in plist. Can you share your code showing how you are populating the dataSource?

Comment: It works now. I wrote wrong word when calling chackDB in AppDelegate.h . I'm sorry for carelessness. And thanks for paying attention to DataSource.